# Optimizing a Django `.exists()` query

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I have a `.exists()` query in an app I am writing. I want to optimize it.

The current ORM expression yields SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (1) AS "a",
  "the_model"."id",
... snip every single column on the_model
FROM "the_model"
WHERE (
...snip criteria...
LIMIT 1
```

The explain plan looks like this:

```
Limit  (cost=176.60..176.63 rows=1 width=223)
  ->  Unique  (cost=176.60..177.40 rows=29 width=223)
        ->  Sort  (cost=176.60..176.67 rows=29 width=223)
              Sort Key: id, ...SNIP...
              ->  Index Scan using ...SNIP... on ...SNIP... (cost=0.43..175.89 rows=29 width=223)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = 6)
                    Filter: ...SNIP...
```

If I manually modify the above SQL and remove the individual table columns so it looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (1) AS "a",
FROM "the_model"
WHERE (
...snip criteria...
LIMIT 1
```

the explain plan shows a couple fewer steps, which is great.

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..175.89 rows=1 width=4)
  ->  Unique  (cost=0.43..175.89 rows=1 width=4)
        ->  Index Scan using ...SNIP... on ...SNIP...  (cost=0.43..175.89 rows=29 width=4)
              Index Cond: (user_id = 6)
              Filter: ...SNIP...
```

I can go further by removing the `DISTINCT` keyword from the query, thus yielding an even shallower execution plan, although the cost saving here is minor:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..6.48 rows=1 width=4)
  ->  Index Scan using ..SNIP... on ..SNIP...  (cost=0.43..175.89 rows=29 width=4)
        Index Cond: (user_id = 6)
        Filter: ..SNIP...
```

I can modify the ORM expression using `.only('id')` to select only one field. However, that does not result in the result I would like. It is doing an unnecessary sort on `id`. Ideally, I would like to do a `.only(None)`, since none of the columns are needed here. They only add weight.

I would also like to remove the `DISTINCT` keyword, if possible. I don't think it adds much execution time if the columns are removed though.

It seems like this could be done across the board, as `.exists()` returns a boolean. None of the returned columns are used for anything. They only complicate the query and reduce performance.

Comment: What version of Django are you using, and what code is causing that query? When I try `User.objects.exists()` it runs `SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "auth_user" LIMIT 1` which is what I'd expect.

Comment: I am using Django 1.11.5. I will look around to see if any custom code is interfering with this and causing the extra columns to be selected.

Comment: There was a `.distinct()` call applied to my QuerySet in a place I was no aware of. This was messing everything up.

Answer (score 0):

I found that during my QuerySet construction, `.distinct()` was being called before my `.exists()`. It was causing the columns to be selected unnecessarily.